# BCD to 7 Segment Decoder Schematic: Need help fitting in page

Tags: fpga, schematics, 7segmentdisplay, ise

I am working on the schematic for a BCD to 7 segment decoder right now. I understand the logic, but it is the design of the schematic that I need help with.

Here is my schematic so far:

[image: Schematic]

As you can see, I only have three outputs done and I need to add four more. The problem that I am having is everything is so vertical and there is so much white space to the right. I would like to be able to fit in all in one page without having to zoom really far out, because then you can't read the inputs or outputs. I guess I just feel like there is a more simple or efficient way that I can be doing this. In the truth table we are using 1010-1110 as don't cares, and 1111 as 0 for all segments to be off.

Comment: This is a question about being artistic methinks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question about being artistic I think but, try rotating everything thru 90 degrees or using net-names to connect things to get rid of the main mass of connections. Not sure if you can use net-names to connect small stubs of wire in your program but I suspect you can. Try this rotated view: -

[image]

There is a lot of white space between the parts you've drawn - I'm sure you can cram a few more parts in if you stick with the same diagram philosophy. Alternatively, look up a 74xxxx chip that does the same thing and copy how it [portrays](http://www.hqew.net/product-data/DM74LS47N/DM74LS47N-CircuitDiagram.html) its internal logic.

Answer (score 2):

Can you zoom out a bit to get more space?

If you slide the gates a little closer together, you should be able to get a 4th output in.

I would put net labels on all the vertical lines, and add another column of outputs on the right.  You can then connect the vertical lines of the two groups together using the net labels.

To get more space, I often tell the CAD system that I'm working on a "B" size (11 x 17") sheet, then print it on letter size paper, and/or spread the drawing over several sheets, using off-sheet connectors and a master (parent) sheet to connect everything together.